# Can someone help me understand this one line of code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, iterator

I'm doing a lab using each and yield

I've almost finished the lab and understand it somewhat just need help full grasping this one line.

yield(collection[i])

```
def my_collect(array)
  i = 0
  collect = []
  while i < array.length
    collect << yield(array[i])
    i+=1
  end
  collect
end
```

Comment: Consider the following: `my_collect([1,2,3]) { |n| n*n } #=> [1, 4, 9]` and `my_collect([1,2,3]) { |n| (1.fdiv(n)).round(4) } #=> [1.0, 0.5, 0.3333]`. `yield(array[i])` *yields* to the block, passing the argument `array[i]`. The result of the block calculation is then returned and appended to the array `collect`.

Answer (score 3):

The `yield` keyword — in association with a block — allows to pass a set of additional instructions during a method invocation.

This mechanism allows you to customise a method depending on your needs.

***What’s a block ?***

A block is part of the Ruby method syntax.
This means that when a block is recognised by the Ruby parser then it’ll be associated to the invoked method and literally replaces the yields in the method.

*I also advise you to replace your `while` loop with `.each`*

```
def my_collect(array)
  collect = []
  array.each { |a| collect << yield(a) }
  collect
end

my_collect([1, 2, 3]) { |n| n + 1 }  produces  ->  [2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Why not go a step further and use `map`? `array.map { |a| yield(a) }` would suffice for the method :)